# insert xml data to sql server 2005 table using vb.net windows form

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2005

I have exported data from a SQL Server table into a XML file and the output looks like this:

Filename = 11190.xml
Table name = LRTest

```
<NewDataSet>
   <LRTest>
      <LR_No>12807</LR_No>
      <LR_Date>2011-10-01T16:50:00+05:30</LR_Date>
      <Bkg_Stn>CHATRAL</Bkg_Stn>
      <FrmShort>CTR</FrmShort>
      <Dst>BOLLARAM</Dst>
      <ToShort>BOL</ToShort>
      <Consignor_Name>Meso Carbon Indus</Consignor_Name>
      <Consignee_Name>Dr.Reddy Lab.</Consignee_Name>
      <Pvt_Mark>0</Pvt_Mark>
      <Discription>Bag</Discription>
      <Article>40</Article>
      <Weight>800</Weight>
      <Value>0</Value>
      <Pmt_Mode>Topay</Pmt_Mode>
      <DoorDel>YES</DoorDel>
      <Freight>3600</Freight>
      <BC>30</BC>
      <Handling>120</Handling>
      <Others>0</Others>
      <S_Tax>115</S_Tax>
      <Amount>4565</Amount>
      <Initial>angel</Initial>
      <Report_No>11190</Report_No>
      <Rep_Date>2011-10-04T16:09:00+05:30</Rep_Date> 
   </LRTest>
</NewDataSet>
```

more.....

Now I want to save the above XML file into my SQL Server 2005 table

With the same columns using vb.net windows forms, in every exported xml file there are 100 to 200 records.

Guys please give me the exact exmp. code please........

Comment: Why would you export data to xml only to just import it right back in ? Btw, if you didn't ask "please give me the exact exmp. code" you wouldn't have been down voted. No one is going to do your work for you if you need help on how to do it, try something or write something and people will help you expand what you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using vb.net, then a good place to start might be the xmltextreader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx#Y701

From that you should be able to get your xml into vb, then getting it back into sql will just be an INSERT query to your database every closing lrtest test

Showing some code will always get you better answers though.